# A Plague Tale: Innocence: Captain Sidekick achievement

Tags: achievements, a-plague-tale-innocence

I am missing only one achievement in A Plague Tale: Innocence. It is the Captain Sidekick achievement, and requires you to follow Lord Nicholas while remaining unseen as he walks from the Grand Inquisitor to Beatrice.

No matter what I do, though, I keep getting seen and killed. I saw two video clips of people who got the achievements, but following their advice does not work - I must be too slow or too fast or something. I'll keep trying, but if anyone can point me to a video or instructions that they could follow successfully, please advise :-)

Comment: Do you know where it goes wrong? Or do you just follow the exact path but the achievement won't show up?

Comment: It goes wrong in the middle of the courtyard. Every. Single. Time. :-)

Comment: I finally did it. The instructions on this page helped me: https://www.powerpyx.com/a-plague-tale-innocence-chapter-14-blood-ties-walkthrough/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide gave me the instruction I needed. I kept getting caught in the North-center of the courtyard, but the reason was because I was not running at that time, still crouching.

Here is the walkthrough that guided me through that: https://www.powerpyx.com/a-plague-tale-innocence-chapter-14-blood-ties-walkthrough/